# Variable declared in header not declared in class scope

Tags: c++, oop, class, scope

This header file appears to declare the variable user_matrix but when I use it in the default constructor it appears not to be declared.

This is the header file:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

class matrix{
 public:

  float** user_matrix;
  int n;

  matrix(int n1,int initiate);

};
```

This is the code that I try and use it in.

```
#include"matrix.h"

using namespace std;

matrix::matrix(int n1,int initiate){
  n=n1;
  user_matrix=NULL;
}


int main(){
  return 0;}
```

Can you suggest where I am going wrong or point me in the right direction for this? Many thanks for any assistance rendered.

edit2:Turns out it was this file in the directory causing the problem matrix.h.gch.

edit: As requested this is all the code.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

//using namespace std;

class matrix{

  //float** random_mat(int size);

 public:

  float** user_matrix;
  int n;


  matrix(int n1,int initiate);
  /*~matrix(){int i;if(user_matix!=NULL){for(i=0;i<n;i++){delete[] user_matrix[i];};delete[] user_matrix;};}

  matrix multiply(matrix matrix1,matix matrix2);
  matrix add(matrix matrix1,matrix matrix2);
  matrix inverse();

  float** sub_matrix(float** matrix1,int i,int j,int n);
  float det();

  void display();
  void display(matrix matrix1);*/


    };
```

---

```
#include"matrix.h"

using namespace std;
matrix::matrix(int n1,int initiate){
  n=n1;
  user_matrix=NULL;

  /*switch(initiate){

  case 1 :
    int i;
    user_matrix=new float* [n1];
    for(i=0;i<n1;i++){
      user_matrix[i] =new float [n1];}

    break;
  case 2 :
    user_matrix=random_mat(n);
    break;
  case 3 :
    user_matrix=NULL;

    }*/
}


int main(){

  //matrix m1(1,1);
  return 0;}
```

Comment: You have two variables named `user-matrix`: a `float` and a `float**`.

Comment: This was a holdover from other test, this does not cause the error. When I compile without it I still get the same error.

Comment: You're still **missing the semicolon** to terminate `class matrix {...}`. Is that in your original code too?

Comment: I don't see any "default constructor" in the code you posted. What line gives you the error? What is the error message?

Comment: More information is needed: compiler(+version) + errors

Comment: Hi thanks for your help on this. I have added the semi-colon but it still causes the same error.  error: ‘user_matrix’ was not declared in this scope

Comment: @user1750289 Then edit your question again to *show your actual code*.

Comment: @user1750289: The code you posted (assuming the implied updates) will not generate any errors. You need to post something that at least resembles the real code you are using. Why is your post continues to state that the error happens in the "default constructor", while there no default constructor in the code you posted?

Comment: I using g++ and it is version 4.6 the error I get is `error: ‘user_matrix’ was not declared in this scope` for the line that contains `user_matrix=NULL;`.

Comment: @user1750289: The code you posted will not produce this error in g++ 4.6. Post real code. (And the constructor you posted is not "default").

Comment: Added full code as requested.

Comment: matrix.h.gch seemed to be causing it not to compile, I don't know what produced it.

Comment: I see no errors there. Meanwhile, `.gch` is a precomiler header file. Sometimes they go stale and cause problems. Delete the `.gch` and recompile (the compiler will create the `.gch` file anew).

Comment: Well done thats what I informed you of.

Answer (score 3):

You appear to have two data members with the same name:

```
float** user_matrix;
int n;
float user_matrix;
```

This cannot work.

Besides that, you are missing a semi-colon after the class declaration:

```
class matrix{
....
};
```

//   ^ here!

Comment: This was a holdover from other test, this does not cause the error.

Answer (score 1):

`user_matrix` is declared twice. Once as `float**` and once as a `float`. `float**` can be set to null, but a `float` cannot. The compiler is not accepting you setting the `float user_matris` to null because it is a `float` and therefore not nullable. Rename one of these `user_matrix`, and you should see your problem go away.